# Problems using git push

Tags: git

I have some changes to push from my staging site to my production site, but when I try to push to the remote directory it says that the changes are already up to date.

I have used git remote -v while cd'd into my staging directory and it returns:

- bare /(url)/bareStagingRepo.git (fetch)
- bare /(url)/bareStagingRepo.git (push)

Using "git push bare master" returns the "up to date" message, but the changes are not made.

.

Comment: That's a shame. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: try `git commit` and the `git push`

Answer (score 0):

1. Git is never wrong. If it says that your repo is up to date, then it is up to date. You just need to verify, how it is up to date :-)
2. Type "git log" and check the last commit in your branch. Also check the "git log" output in the master branch. The commit ids will be same.
3. You must have some changes which you have not committed. It is also possible that you may have stashed the changes but forgot to apply them again.

Comment: Yeah, so this is probably the problem, master is not showing the commit but the branch is. I tried to push directly from the branch that I was making the changes on, and it did some work, but the changes still didn't take effect. My branch is called staticHeader and the remote is called bare. I did git push bare staticHeader.

Comment: "git push bare staticHeader" would have created a new branch at the server. Merge the server's branch into master and then pull the changes into your master